# Как удалить элемент многомерного массива по совподающим значениям из подмассивов?

Tags: массивы, php

```
foreach($Goods as $index1 =>$massiv1)
{
  $current=$massiv1['Link'];
  do{
    next($Goods);
  }
  while($current!=$massiv1['Link']);//Делаем пока не равно
  if(($current)==($massiv1['Link']))
  {
    unset($Goods[$index1]);

  }

}
```

нужно, чтобы допустим если в одном подмассиве ссылка равна ссылке из другого то этот элемент  основного массива удаляется..
а тут все удаляется почему-то..

Comment: знание языка хромает

Comment: тут люди собираются чтобы помогать друг другу... если вы считаете не так, то извините...про что вы сказали знание языка?то что я совпОдающим написал...так я торопился

Answer (score 2):

Конечно все и удаляется, ведь по действию в третьей строке:

```
$current=$massiv1['Link'];
```

Т.е. уже понятно что `$current==$massiv1['Link']` вернет `true` и ниже стоящее условие будет всегда выполняться:

```
if(($current)==($massiv1['Link']))
{
unset($Goods[$index1]);

}
```

По всей видимости в третьей строке должна быть другая переменная.

Answer (score 0):

Вы приравниваете `$current=$massiv1['Link'];`
А дальше сравниваете `$current` с `$massiv1['Link'] (if(($current)==($massiv1['Link'])))`.

Потеряли переменную и ошибка в логике

Comment: Прогоняйте по двойному циклу, т.е. первый цикл обход массива, второй подцикл обход массива, но с условием, что если тот же массив выходим из подцикла. Вроде так можно